# JQuery UI Dialog - loading external page prevents dialog from reopening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

If I load a JQuery UI Dialog without loading external content, the dialog can be closed with the "Close" button and the dialog can be re-opened multiple times.  If I load content in, neither of these two capabilities works.  Code below.  Any hints??  Thanks in advance!!

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#viewdonationsdialog').dialog({
             autoOpen:false,
             modal:'true',
             width:600,
             height:400,
             buttons: {
                Close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
             }
          });
         $('#viewdonationslink').click(openDonationsDialog);            
        });

        var openDonationsDialog = function(){
/* Including the next line causes failure.  
Removing it results in success (except, of course, that my page content isn't loaded!! */

            $('#viewdonationsdialog').load('/donationsdata');       

/* And then there's the rest... */

            $('#viewdonationsdialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        };
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console when you try to open the dialog after loading your content?

Comment: Not anymore. But there were. The following were missing from the stylesheets directory:

jquery.alerts.css
jquery.autocomplete.css
ui.theme.css

So I put them in there.  Now the same failure occurs (with no error in the console) but strangely, the title bar of the dialog vanishes... it appears, then goes away after the content loads.

So I'm thinking you're on to something here -- might be that these files are relevant, and perhaps I now have a conflicting version of these files relative to the jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css I'm using.  I'll investigate that.  

Meanwhile - Other guesses, anyone?

Comment: UPDATE:  Eliminating ui.theme brought me back to original state:  Title bar does not vanish, but failure remains.  Will continue to investigate.

Comment: MORE UPDATE:  I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min and jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.  Thought maybe I needed to update JQuery to 1.8 so I tried.  Didn't fix the problem, but the Close button suddenly got super-small.  So not sure there's a version conflict.  
I'm pretty inexperienced with JS and JQuery, so any pointers would be awesome!